# Router infected; Factory reset not working

Tags: malware, wifi, virus, router, url-redirection

Recently, I was being redirected (occasionally, not every time) by "ilkmawgod.site" (no information on google) to malicious webpages. I scanned my every thing using quick heal, but it didn't find anything. I noticed this was happening with all the devices at home connected to the home router. Further, when I used mobile data there was no redirect. I figured out that my router must be infected. I factory-reset my router, but now I am being redirected by "netpatas.com" (a redirecting virus according to google) to malicious ads (on all devices connected to the home router, occasionally). What should I do? Is there something that I missed while factory-resetting my router? Can I clean this thing off my router or I have to buy a new one?

Comment: Have you tried re-flashing the firmware?

Comment: I don't know what is that. Can you tell me what to do? @multithr3at3d

Comment: Unfortunately, we are not a malware removal site. You need a new router or learn how to re-flash the firmware. Either way, you need to contact your ISP's support.